# Android Application for Sending a File using Bluetooth OBEX Object Push Profile (OPP)

Tags: android

I tried the following application example for sending a file over Bluetooth OPP in Android Froyo.

Please sugest any solution for this, thanks in advance.

**My Application Code:**

```
public class BtAppExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Munnar/1.jpg";
        Log.e("BtAppExample","Uri is: "+Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString()); 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(BluetoothShare.URI,Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString()); 
        values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, "90:4C:E5:D9:0E:D0");
        values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND); 
        Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
        Uri contentUri = getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);

        }
}
```

**My Manifest file:**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BtAppExample"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Will you post some error messages?
I'd like to specify what to be wrong of your source

Comment: @Sam..Have you executed the above code or else tried something differed.I to facing the same problem.Is't possible to provide me the solution.